# Use Interface with different namespaces in typescript

Tags: inheritance, interface, typescript, namespaces

I want to create an interface in 'parent.a' namespace and I want to use that interface in 'parent' namespace.

Is there any way to do that, please help me on this.

I have found one solution to access classes from different namespaces [access class from namespace](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/javascript-namespacing-with-typescript-internal-modules/) but I need to work with interface not classes.

my example:

```
module Parent.AInterface {    

    export interface AInterface {
        setParent(): void;
    }

}
```

My other module

```
module Parent {

    export class ParentClass implements AInterface {

    }

}
```

while doing so.. I'm getting an error that says Cannot find name 'AInterface'

please help me on this.

Comment: Are both modules declared in different files? If so, have you tried adding something like this ´///<reference path='pathToFile/first_file.ts'/>´ in the second class i.e. module Parent...  ?

Answer (score 1):

You should mention module name before interface name:

```
module Parent.AInterface {    

    export interface AInterface {
        setParent(): void;
    }

} 


module Parent {

    export class ParentClass implements AInterface.AInterface {
        setParent() {
        }
    }

}
```

This works fine for me in the typescript playground.

Answer (score 0):

Parent.ts

```
///<reference path="./Parent.AInterface.ts" />
module Parent {
     export class ParentClass implements AInterface.AInterface {}
}
```